# Smoothing polygons from a TIN-interpolated pointdata layer in Qgis

Tags: raster, qgis, smoothing

I would like to smoothen polygons from a TIN-interpolated point-data layer.

I have a TIN-interpolated layer from a data-point layer with attribute quantity. I have added this style:
[Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU4iZ.png)

This is the result (when zooming in):
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMKIy.png)

The resulting raster is quite ok but I would like to smoothen the polygons so it´s more like this:
[Wished result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57sPa.png)

Does anyone have a clue how to achieve that?